# why selenium.isConfirmationPresent() returns true after using chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation

Tags: java, selenium

I am having a code like the following

**selenium.chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation()**;

**selenium.click("deleteRequest");**// confirm dialog will be displayed on clicking the button

System.out.println("is confirmation present "+**selenium.isConfirmationPresent()**);

Eventhough i am using selenium.chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation(), please let me know why **selenium.isConfirmationPresent()** returns true.

But selenium.isConfirmationPresent() returns false after

**selenium.getConfirmation()**;

Is it mandatory to use selenium.getConfirmation(), as i am not able to do further processing. It says

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: There was an unexpected Confirmation! [Are you sure to delete selected request(s)?]
com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97)
        at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. **chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation()** dictates the behaviour of **getConfirmation()**. Calling [**getConfirmation()**](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.ISelenium.GetConfirmation.html) effectively "consumes" the confirmation popup. You must use **getConfirmation** or **verifyConfirmation** before continuing your test, as any other Selenium command will fail if you do not handle the popup with a getConfirmation call.

> By default, the confirm function will
>   return true, having the same effect as
>   manually clicking OK. This can be
>   changed by prior execution of the
>   chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation
>   command. If an confirmation is
>   generated but you do not get/verify
>   it, the next Selenium action will
>   fail.

So your code could be:

```
selenium.chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation();

selenium.click("deleteRequest")

selenium.getConfirmation();
```